# Is there any way to set a gemfire partitioned region to expire data?

Tags: spring, gemfire

As far as I can tell, the only values for data expiry in a gemfire region ((LOCAL_)DESTROY, (LOCAL_)INVALIDATE) are unsupported for partitioned regions. Is there something that I'm missing, or do I just need to pick a different region type if I want entries to expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annnnd I'm dumb.

I was setting the region-expiry attribute, not the entry-expiry.